# Next Js Text content did not match

Tags: next.js

```
`import Link from "next/link";
 import Image from "next/image";
 import logo from "@/assets/home/footerLogo.svg";
 import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";
 import {
  FaInstagram,
  FaLinkedin,
  FaTwitter,
  FaYoutube,
  FaWhatsapp,
  FaEnvelope,
  FaMapMarkerAlt,
  FaPhone,
 } from "react-icons/fa";

 function FooterComponent() {
  const { t } = useTranslation("footer");
  console.log(
    "Namespace and key used in FooterComponent:",
   t("reachUs")
   );

const reachUsTranslation = t("reachUs");
  console.log("Translated 'reachUs' string:", reachUsTranslation);

return (
<div className="bg-[#06264E] text-white py-20">
  <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
    <Image src={logo} alt="logo" />
    <hr />
  </div>
  <hr />

  <div className="container mx-auto flex flex-col lg:flex-row gap-20 px-10 lg:px-20 mt-10 ">
    <div className="flex lg:gap-10 justify-between lg:justify-start">
      <div className="space-y-6 lg:me-20 ">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-xl">{t("reachUs")}</h1>

        <div className="space-y-6">
          <p className="flex gap-2 items-center">
            <FaPhone size={24} color="#007bff" /> +49 176417926
          </p>
          <p className="flex gap-2">
            <FaEnvelope size={24} color="#000" />
            contact@ausbilding-assist.de
          </p>
          <p className="flex gap-2">
            <FaMapMarkerAlt size={24} color="#e65100" /> Hochdorfer Steige
            27
            <br /> Remseck Am Neckar, <br /> 71686 Germany
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="space-y-6 text-sm flex flex-col">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-xl">{t("company")}</h1>
        <Link href={"/about-us"}>{t("aboutUs")}</Link>
        <Link href={"/contact-us"}>{t("contactUs")}</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="flex lg:gap-20 justify-between lg:justify-start ">
      <div className="space-y-6 text-sm flex flex-col">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-xl">{t("legal")}</h1>
        <Link href={"/privacy-policy"}>{t("privacyPolicy")}</Link>
      </div>

      <div className="space-y-6 text-sm flex flex-col">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-xl">{t("quickLinks")}</h1>
        <Link href={"/talents"}>{t("forTalents")}</Link>
        <Link href={"/employers"}>{t("forEmployers")}</Link>
        <Link href={"/services/visa"}>{t("visaServices")}</Link>
        <Link href={"/services/loan"}>{t("loanServices")}</Link>
        <Link href={"/services/accommodation-support"}>
          {t("accommodationSupport")}
        </Link>
        <Link href={"/services/on-arrival-support"}>
          {t("onArrivalSupport")}
        </Link>
        <Link href={"/services/blocked-Account-services"}>
          {t("blockedAccountServices")}
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h1 className="font-bold text-xl mb-6 text-center lg:text-start">
        {t("connectWithUs")}
      </h1>
      <div className="flex gap-4 justify-center  text-center lg:text-start ">
        <FaInstagram size={32} color="#e4405f" />
        <FaLinkedin size={32} color="#0077b5" />
        <FaTwitter size={32} color="#1da1f2" />
        <FaYoutube size={32} color="#ff0000" />
        <FaWhatsapp size={32} color="#25d366" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
}

export default FooterComponent;xt`


and layout component is:  

`import { Layout, theme } from "antd";
  // import HeaderComponent from "@/components/UI/Shared/HeaderComponent.jsx";

 import FooterComponent from "../UI/Shared/FooterComponent";
 import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";
 export async function getStaticProps({ locale }) {
 return {
  props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
       "footer",
       ])),
    },
  };
}

const { Content } = Layout;

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
return (
<Layout>
  {/* <HeaderComponent /> */}
  <Content>
   {children}
  </Content>
  <FooterComponent/>
</Layout>
);
};

export default RootLayout;
```

now geting this error:

client.js:2 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in .

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "Reach us" Client: "reachUs"

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Component Stack
h1
div
div
div
div
FooterComponent
div
eval
Layout
RootLayout
MyApp
`

I tried all solutions from here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

I want to translate this footer into 2 different language.

I have done 16 pages they are translated ok but footer is not rendering the right text.

Comment: Can you please add a version of the next js?

Comment: "next": "^13.4.19",